# How to enable conda commands on another user profile on MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

I'm installing Anaconda and a bunch of packages on a lot of MacBooks for an upcoming class. I'm about halfway through all the machines and just learned I've been installing Anaconda and all of the packages on the Administrator account when I should have been installing it on the regular user account. Conda commands work just fine on the admin account, but when I type "conda list" or "conda --version" on the regular user account that it needs to work on, I get:

-bash: conda: command not found

How do I enable anaconda commands on another user account? Thanks!

I have already tried a bunch of things to do with .bash_profile but frankly, I have no idea what I'm doing with those.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly when I installed anaconda there was an option to install for all users or just the logged in profile

Comment: I see that, but that option is greyed out for me

Comment: Is the account you're logged in as an admin account

Comment: Yeah, as far as i know

Comment: I would ensure that the account is an admin and then try again. I apologize I don't know how to verify this on a mac